# Can I travel to other European Countries on my Visa?

Tags: visas, europe, schengen

I am living in Poland and my visa is valid until June 2014.

So can I go and visit other European countries or I can only visit Poland cities?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  This is a bit confusing for us.  What kind of visa do you hold, and which European countries would you like to visit?

Comment: And also, what citizenship do you hold?

Answer (score 3):

You don' mention what Visa you currently have.
Let's asume however that you have a Polish Visa (If you had a Schengen Visa you wouldn't be asking this question).

Persons in possession of some national Visa of a Schengen country have travel rights in the whole of the Schengen area as if they had a Schengen visa. That means that the 90 days in 180 rule applies. At least officially.

In practice, since there are no immigration controls between the different states within Schengen you can mostly ignore these rules. I you want to travel to another Schengen country, just do so.

Comment: The one caveat here is that if you choose to ignore the "90 in 180" rule, you need to make sure to exit the Schengen zone safely (i.e. either leave from the country where you have your visa, or have your story straight on where you were and when if questioned when exiting via a different country). In practice, people flout that rule all the time, but that doesn't mean there won't be consequences if you are caught flouting it.

Comment: And if one is in the possession of let's say an Israeli passport the 90/180 rules apply but the travel is not restricted only to the Schengen zone.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Schengen visa, you can only visit countries in the Schengen zone (like Germany and Spain, but not England). More information here: http://www.workpermit.com/germany/schengen_visa.htm